# how can form action and post method together work?

Tags: php, mysql, database, forms, action

Below is my code. If I do not use this link in form action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr". The form of data inserted successfully in my database. But, when I using this action link. in the database, form data not sending

so, how can form action and post method together work?

Actually Here is what I want to after click submit button, will be successfully title data insert into my database. and then page redirects to the PayPal checkout page.

```
<?php
$database_username = 'root';
$database_password = '';
$pdo_conn = new PDO( 'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=shipping_pro', $database_username, $database_password );

if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST' && isset($_POST['insert'])) {
  $sql = "INSERT INTO posts (title) VALUES (:title)";
  $pdo_statement = $pdo_conn->prepare( $sql );
  $result = $pdo_statement->execute( array( 
    ':title'=>$_POST['title']
  ) );
  if (!empty($result) ){
    header('location:index.php');
  }
}
?>
<form method="POST" action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr">
  <input type="text" name="title" placeholder="Title" />
  <input name="insert" type="submit" value="Add">
</form>
```

Comment: Your form is targeting the paypal website.

Comment: use Ajax to send the data to the db and use the ajax callback to submit the form to Paypal?

Comment: When you are not given action to form it will submit to same page and when you provide action to form then it will submit a form to that URL

Comment: @Jeto This is my paypal main script.[link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1scjdZ7E7DlemQdg4qur8NOM533j_KfCN/view)
 I need to save option value in my database

Comment: Hi, @RamRaider. I tried callback function. But if i used callback function. PayPal subscribe script not working in call back function. it be working only in action.

Comment: @SagarSainkar I can't understand your comment . explain me details please.

Comment: Can you show me how you tried to implement the callback method and explain  "not working" ?

Answer (score 0):

I have just quickly tested the `use ajax and let the callback submit the form` idea I mentioned in the comment above - seems to work OK so would be keen to know why this does not work for you - intrinsically the form would appear to all intents and purposes to Paypal exactly as it should so I cannot see why it would not work ( but perhaps not enough coffee yet? )

By preventing the SUBMIT button from performing it's default action when clicked ( `e.preventDefault()` ) you interrupt the flow of the form and can inject your own logic prior to submission. Rather than send the form immediately you send whatever data you want to the PHP script, it then logs to db and sends a reply to the ajax function saying "Hi, I have finished - proceed" etc and then the callback will actually continue to submit the form.

```
<?php
    if( $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST' ){
        ob_clean();

        /* log details to db */

        /*

        $database_username = 'root';
        $database_password = '';
        $pdo_conn = new PDO( 'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=shipping_pro', $database_username, $database_password );

        INSERT INTO posts (title) VALUES (:title) etc etc

        */

        /* send some sort of response to ajax callback */
        exit("banana's tend to be yellow and monkeys love 'em!");
    }
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang='en'>
    <head>
        <meta charset='utf-8' />
        <title>Paypal: Record details to db and then submit to Paypal</title>
        <script>
            const ajax=function(url,params,callback){
                let xhr=new XMLHttpRequest();
                xhr.onload=function(){
                    if( this.status==200 && this.readyState==4 )callback.call( this, this.response )
                };
                xhr.onerror=function(e){
                    alert(e)
                };
                xhr.open( 'POST', url, true );
                xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type','application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
                xhr.setRequestHeader('X-Requested-With','XMLHttpRequest');
                xhr.send( params );
            };

            const clickhandler=function(e){
                e.preventDefault();

                let form=this.parentNode;

                const callback=function(r){
                    alert( 'Response from saving to db: '+r+'\nNow submit the form to PayPal!!!' );
                    form.submit();
                };
                ajax( location.href, 'title='+this.previousElementSibling.value, callback )
            };
            document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', ()=>{
                document.querySelector( 'form > input[type="submit"][name="insert"]' ).addEventListener( 'click', clickhandler )
            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form method="POST" action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr">
            <input type='hidden' name='cmd' value='_s-xclick' />
            <input type='hidden' name='hosted_button_id' value='S2QXVVPPL7EUE' />
            <input type='hidden' name='on0' value='BANANA' />
            <input type='hidden' name='os0' value='BANANA' />
            <input type='hidden' name='currency_code' value='GBP' />

            <input type="text" name="title" placeholder="Title" />
            <input name="insert" type="submit" value="Add">
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: please explain what you mean by `"one more input file"`

Comment: hi, @ramraider. Thanks for your a great comment. this comment working good.One more question. could you tell me please. How can i add one more input file. <input type="text" name="phone" /> . when i add one more file. and try to insert in database. showing this massage. https://ibb.co/tXwwz0Y

Comment: Hi, @ramraider. here is full code. https://docs.google.com/document/d/1Ang6oJgCbnW3cXozbHLyO45O79K62EJygLFrbKt1oRc/edit

Comment: You can try `ajax( location.href, 'title='+document.querySelector('input[name="title"]').value+'&phone='+document.querySelector('input[name="phone"]').value, callback )` - you might be better using a `FormData` object though. Good luck - don't forget to mark as correct if this helped

Comment: hi, @ramraider . Thanks for your kind help. Finally It worked. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try this below code

```html
<?php
$database_username = 'root';
$database_password = '';
$pdo_conn = new PDO( 'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=shipping_pro', $database_username, $database_password );

if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST' && isset($_POST['insert'])) {
  $sql = "INSERT INTO posts (title) VALUES (:title)";
  $pdo_statement = $pdo_conn->prepare( $sql );
  $result = $pdo_statement->execute( array( 
    ':title'=>$_POST['title']
  ) );
  if (!empty($result) ){
    header('location:https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr')
  }
}
?>
<form method="POST" action="index.php">
  <input type="text" name="title" placeholder="Title" />
  <input name="insert" type="submit" value="Add">
</form>
```

Comment: @MdRumman please mark it as worked answer if it worked for you :)